# Visual homology and the fundamental group

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[image]

This question is about the relationship between the first homology group and the fundamental group. It is true that the first homology group is isomorphic to the abelianisation of the fundamental group.

The diagram on the left shows a generating set for $H_1(M_2)$ (the genus 2 surface). The question asks to find linear combinations of the generators which equal the homology classes depicted on the right.

If thought of as loops in the fundamental group, the question seems easy, with $c = a_2 b_2 a_2^{-1} b_2^{-1}$ for example.

When moving to homology however, I'm not even sure why those "loops" (which are actually cycles) generate the homology group. Can I take the element $c = a_2 b_2 a_2^{-1} b_2^{-1}$, and just say it's trivial in the abelianisation? If so, then which chain is c the boundary of?

Comment: $a_2b_2a_2^{-1}b_2^{-1}$ is the boundary of a subsurface of your genus $2$ torus. You can turn this into a chain by triangulating this subsurface, orienting the simplices consistently and taking their sum. The boundary of this sum is the boundary of the surface.

Comment: @GrumpyParsnip, ah I see, so if i can see a subsurface for which something is a boundary, then I can always triangulate? One more thing, is it possible to draw pictures like this for second homology, or does it get a bit weird? Thanks

Comment: Any manifold can be interpreted as a chain either by triangulating (which works for most manifolds) or by the "fundamental class" construction. If the manifold is boundaryless, it is a cycle. It's true that all 1,2,3 dimensional classes can be represented by maps of surfaces, but once you get to dimension 4, this stops working, if I recall correctly. You can google representing homology classes by manifolds for more info.

Comment: Brilliant, I'll have a look at this thanks